# How to use less.js with node.js to watch .less files in a folder?

Tags: node.js, less, watch

I am looking for a simple guide to setting up server-side watching and compiling .less files in a folder using less.js and node.js. Bryan wrote about it in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/24045/47747).

Unfortunately, the instructions to [Server-side usage](http://lesscss.org/#-server-side-usage) on lesscss.org are of a little avail to somebody who is new to node.js.

I have tried command line usage: `$ lessc styles.less > styles.css`.

I have also tried 'watchr' and 'watch-less' and it all works. However, I am looking for a pure node.js + less.js solution. I am sure there is somebody who will be able to plainly explain how to configure node.js and less.js to watch .less files in a folder. Thanks.

Comment: I have used a [watch-less](https://github.com/Raynos/so642/blob/master/src/init/watch-less.js) file in the past. I think that's node 0.4 though so the code needs to be upgraded.

Answer (score 4):

I have created demo project to show how it works. You can find it here https://github.com/corpix/watcherDemo

After clone enter project directory and execute `npm install` to install less Node.js module.
Try running `index.js` and change `.less` file into `less_files/` directory, modified file will be compiled and placed into `css_files/`

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I have been looking for.

Comment: it seems to fail if you're using @import rules

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, I have seen a lot of the same threads and answers.

If you are like me and don't want any more code bloat than you already have then just download a LESS app for Win/Mac/Nix and it will auto-compile every time you save your .less files.

I honestly think this would put less of a load on the server because you only need to upload your compiled and minified files at this point.

Comment: "just download a LESS app"... what **is** a LESS app? where is the link?

Comment: I agree in principle, but this shouldn't have any votes until such an app is suggested. I searched for one got to this question!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `less-watch-compiler` to watch for `.less` files. You don't need a main file to watch just like grunt. Just install this plugin:

`npm install -g less-watch-compiler`

or

`yarn global add less-watch-compiler`

Usage:

`less-watch-compiler [options] <source_dir> <destination_dir>`

### Basic example

```
 root 
 └──src
 │    └── main.less
 │    └── aux.less
 └──dist
      └── main.css
```

The project can be compiled with the following command:

`less-watch-compiler src dist main.less`

#### Basic Example 2

less-watch-compiler.config.json

```
{
    "watchFolder": "src",
    "outputFolder": "dist",
    "mainFile": "main.less"
}
```

The project can be compiled with the following command:

```
less-watch-compiler
```

[Source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/less-watch-compiler).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote something that could be what you are looking for. The script will look for .less files in the watch folder and compile them into the output folder. All you need to do is specify the folder you want to watch and the output folder.

> node less-watch-compiler.js FOLDER_TO_WATCH FOLDER_TO_OUTPUT

https://github.com/jonycheung/Dead-Simple-LESS-Watch-Compiler

It skips watching files with names that starts with underscore or a period.

I wrote this for my development process but it should still work on a server. However, you may want to re-consider watching a folder for changes constantly on a live server. It's an expensive operation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use supervisor with -e argument to provide extensions to watch:

```
nohup supervisor -e 'js|ejs|less' $APP_DIR/app.js  1>$APP_DIR/log/app.log 2>&1 &
echo $! > $APP_DIR/pid/app.pid;
```

Taken from node-startup script: https://github.com/chovy/node-startup

The simpler version of this command is:

```
supervisor -e 'js|ejs|less' app.js
```

Answer (score 1):

**I know this is an old post, but came up a few times when I was recently searching for the same thing.**

I have forked and updated the code from jonycheung - and have submitted a merge request.

**Update:** jonycheung has accepted the merge request so his original code is now updated

In the mean time, the code can be found here:

https://github.com/mikestreety/Dead-Simple-LESS-Watch-Compiler

I have also been working on and developing a pure bash script which uses lessc, but does not require a node script to run:

https://github.com/mikestreety/less-watch

Comment: Hm.. need to look into what you wrote there ;) 
I actually did something similar for a single file with options
https://gist.github.com/pixelass/7964010

Comment: Sorry - is that you need to have a look or i need to have a look at what I wrote? Your script looks pretty fantastic! Shame that we've moved to Sass ;)

Comment: It was, that I have to look at what you wrote ;) I made mine a github repo: https://github.com/pixelass/lessc-bash

Comment: @mikestreety - install instructions for `inotifytools` doesn't include Windows. it says something about compile, and I don't even how to do that. gave up, don't want no compiling strange code from the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not direct answer. But here is my comment:

Usually we need this watch during the development phase, where we need to change the less file and see the result without the need of re-running the `lessc` command by every change in less file.

We do this by pure `less.js` in the in the our html. as below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="/path/to/bootstrap.less">
<script src="/path/to/less.js"></script>
```

After the finalizing the development task. You need to run `lessc` only once.

During development your pages may take a liitle more time to load, But if your site is ajax base, and you add this to your template page, it will not be a big deal.